# Copy and Paste Special on SAME CELLS once conditions are met using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to come up with a code and I think I'm missing the last step.

So, I was working on a code to copy cells from column "S" only when the adjacent cell from column "R" = "X".

I came up to something like this:

```vb
Sub PasteContitionalSpecial()

lastRow = Worksheets("orders").Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To lastRow

If Worksheets("orders").Range("R" & r).Value = "Withdraw Now" Then
   Worksheets("orders").Range("S" & r).Copy
```

However, I have NO idea how to paste properly, because I need to paste on the same column "S", but paste as values, when originally "S" had formulas.

If you help me with this code, I'll love you forever. Thanks!

Dany

I tried the string shown above and then Paste Special but had a bug somewhere

Comment: Try `Worksheets("orders").Range("S" & r).Formula = Worksheets("orders").Range("S" & r).Value`